# update only visible objects inside of a SVG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to create a big SVG in d3js, which is bigger than one screen and scrollable. It will by dynamic and contains 1000+ of lines including text and links.

It has a brush on top to move around and zoom in. 
The issue is that the brush performance is very bad on firefox and IE11.

While in chrome the performance is excellent and can draw 2000 lines without any issue. In firefox and IE11 I get serious performance issues even with 200 lines.

To improve performance, my idea is that I only update the objects which are visible on the screen. The others can be updated when user scrolles up/down.

on X-axis, I do it like that

```
var minExtent = brush.extent()[0]
    , maxExtent = brush.extent()[1]
    , visItems = items.filter(function (d) { return d.start < maxExtent && d.end > minExtent});
```

But I cant find out how I can detect if an object in an SVG is visible on the screen on Y-axis. Any idea how this can be achieved.
Or any other hint to improve the performance for FF and IE?

here is an example code https://jsfiddle.net/n841qbfx/

Comment: Firefox already does this for your content internally. Doing it yourself too will simply slow it down even further. The link seems to work without any perf issues for me on my Firefox.

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, when I look into the FF debuger/inspector I can see that all objects(rects/text/...) getting updated with new X-coordinates even if they are not visible on screen.

Also it is very strange, at the beginning speed is ok, but when you just use the slider and move it left-right for 30times it gets slower and slower until it is more or less unusable

Comment: just because they get new co-ordinates doesn't mean they get re-rendered.